# Calling a void method in the same class

Tags: java

so I have a method

```
public void arin(int failure, boolean crash, boolean breakdown, double arinEngine, double arinComputer,
        int arinmorale, double arinRocket, String name, int choice, int fixAttempts) {

}
```

which is empty right now, and I want to call it into my main method. I have tried using run, using return, but nothing is working.
I made it into a static and tried
 `run.arin();` but it said run cant be resolved to a variable.

Comment: Show us how you tried to call the method in main, as well as the EXACT error message you are getting.

Comment: Your `main` method is static.  Your `arin` method is not static, so it need to be called from an instance of the class.

Comment: *I made it into a static and tried  run.arin();* What is `run`? Why would you expect it to work?

Comment: Calling a method in Java is kind of a beginner task. If you're stuck on a specific problem, please clarify. Otherwise, you might want to read up on Java a little more.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class object or make the method static

```
public class YourClassName {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        YourClassName test = new YourClassName();
        test.arin(0, false, false, 0.0, 0.0, 0, 0.0, "", 0, 0);
    }

    public void arin(int failure, boolean crash, boolean breakdown, double arinEngine, double arinComputer,
            int arinmorale, double arinRocket, String name, int choice, int fixAttempts) {

    }
}
```

Comment: can i see the exact code i should use? Sorry, im still new at java

Comment: @Maddie This answer has the main method calling your "shell" method. There is no "call" or "run" or "execute" commands -- you execute a method by method name associate with the class if static or by an instance of the class as in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You would call the method by writing `arin()` but things inside the parenthesis. i.e. `arin(5, true, true, 2.1, 2.2, 6, 3.3, "car", 1, 7);`

Your main method and this void method are in the same class you do not need to create an object for that class.  You can just call it in the main method like I have above.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your static method in the same class that main method, you can use (run) it just by calling it:

```
public class YourClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        arin(0, false, false, 0.0, 0.0, 0, 0.0, "", 0, 0);
    }

    public static void arin(int failure, boolean crash, boolean breakdown, double arinEngine, double arinComputer,
        int arinmorale, double arinRocket, String name, int choice, int fixAttempts) {

    }
}
```